# Vnstat only updates on live?

Tags: centos, bandwidth-control

I trying to configure vnstat...and anyway when I do vnstat -u it does say it updates but data does not change...if I do vnstat -l for live view and then go out of it and do vnstat -u it does update

Is there a way I can do it without being in live all the time?

Answer (score 2):

```
# chown -R vnstat:vnstat /var/lib/vnstat
```

`/var/lib/vnstat/.eth0` is temp file, that may disappear sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Type "`ps aux | grep vnstat`" in a terminal

You should see a line like this:

```
root 1091 0.0 0.0 1956 596 ?  Ss   17:21   0:00 /usr/sbin/vnstatd -d
```

If not, it means the update daemon is not running.
Several causes:
- the computer was not rebooted since you installed vnstat
- the daemon is not installed (type "`ll /etc/init.d/vnstat`" and check that no error message is returned)

As soon as the daemon is running with default settings, you will have updates of stats every 5 minutes.
Just type "`vnstat`" at 5 minutes intervall to validate (check the first line `"Database updated   "`)

Comment: Daemon is running. Still doesn't update :(